# Check if copied file exists and if it's different from source

Tags: bash, shell, powerpc

I have this script which currently works under our x86_64 server, but when we try to run on a ppc64 server it does not work:

```
HOME=$(eval echo ~$(whoami))
CACHE_DIR="$HOME/.jenkins/cache/archive"
CACHE_PATH="$CACHE_DIR"

if [ ! -d $CACHE_PATH ]
 then
   mkdir -p $CACHE_PATH
fi

if output=$(cmp --s requirements.txt $CACHE_PATH/requirements.txt)
then
 echo "cached"
else
 echo "build"
 cp requirements.txt $CACHE_PATH/requirements.txt
fi
```

Output from x86_64

```
ubuntu@x86_agent:~$ bash tester.sh 
build
ubuntu@x86_agent:~$ bash tester.sh 
cached
```

Output from ppc64le ( target folder is empty, always )

```
[xx@ppce64_agent /u/tpereira]$ bash testing.sh 
cached
[xx@ppce64_agent /u/tpereira]$ bash testing.sh 
cached
```

Comment: Do you not trust that `$HOME` is already set correctly? Also, read the `cmp(1)` man pages on the respective systems: I'm guessing the ppc system probably does not like `--s` option.

Comment: Since you're using `mkdir -p`, you don't strictly need to check if the directory exists first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that it is an architecture problem. Could it be that you have slightly different software version (bash, cmp, and so on) that handle the oddities in your script differently?

## Oddities

Delete `HOME=$(eval echo ~$(whoami))`. `HOME` is a built in variable and should be set automatically by bash. Name your variables in lowercase to avoid such name collisions.
Also `~` defaults to the current user's home directory. You could just write `cacheDir=~/.jenkins/cache/archive`

There are two issues in `if output=$(cmp --s requirements.txt $CACHE_PATH/requirements.txt)`.

- The `-s` option should have just one dash, not two.
- Why do you store the output of the command, when you specified, that there shouldn't be any output (`-s`)?

Simply write `if cmp -s requirements.txt "$CACHE_PATH/requirements.txt"`.

## Replacement

Instead of writing your own script, you could use an already existing solution, for instace `rsync`.

Comment: Currently this was just a placeholder solution while we didn't had artifactory, currently everything is being stored there.

Answer (score 1):

You are grabbing the return value wrong.

You are setting your variable equal to the output of `cmp` (the stdout). `cmp` does not display anything, it uses the return value as the answer. This value would be contained in `$?` if `cmp` was the last command run, or you could just do it this way:

```
if cmp -s "$file1" "$file2"
then
  echo "The files match"
else
  echo "The files are different"
fi
```

This works because it is asking if `cmp` completed without errors. Any non-zero return value is seen as an error, and goes to the `else` statement.

Comment: That's what this code does - the return value is used as the conditional; *and* stdout is also captured in the `output` variable. Capturing stdout doesn't affect the exit status, which is still used in the `if` statement.